# Android List View not displaying incomming messages and sending messages first time to the fragment

Tags: android

I am trying to create an chat client even though i have an issue. When I open the app for first time and I open a chat (List View) fragment and if I am send message first time than message is not display in (List View) but when I send second message than both first and second messages are display.

Here is my code link.

http://pastie.org/10548016

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: ok i will post my code